# close child after sigin and reload parent with signin data

Tags: php, javascript, window.open, window.opener

Right now i m using `window.open()` when a user click and a popwindow display login form.
for this i used":

```
<script>
function popupwindow(url, title, w, h) {
    var w = 600;
    var h = 600;
    var left = Number((screen.width/2)-(w/2));
    var tops = Number((screen.height/2)-(h/2));

window.open("child.php", '', width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+tops+', left='+left);


}
</script>
```

a child.php page displaying in popup, but the problem is that, when i login and page redirect to the parent page and reload, its still showing no user is login.
I used these on child page

```
<script>

    function refreshAndClose() {
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
        }


</script>
```

and

```
<body onbeforeunload="refreshAndClose();">
```

Is it possible with this to reload parent page with login detail.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321323/submit-form-reload-parent-and-close-child/36855748#36855748 might help someone

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your login detail in a session variable in child page. Which you can check in the parent page.