# submit form, reload parent, and close child

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have an issue with a cross-IE issue, not necessarily a cross-browser one.

I am trying to open a child window, where a user would submit a form.  On submission, a PHP script should be called to load the child form data.  The child then should reload the parent window containing some of the content that was added in the child form, and also close the child form...

Users will not have any other browser in use other than IE, but different versions (I would prefer to make this fully compliant, but I will settle with different IEs).  I have had no trouble with this in IE10, but I can't get it to work in IE8.  There are users that must use IE8 (they are stuck on XP due to other software that won't run on 7 or 8).

I have tried this:

```
<form name="parts" id="parts" action="tableaddrow_nw.php" method="get" onsubmit="window.opener.document.location.href='q.php?q=<?php echo $q; ?>&memberid=<?php echo $memberid; ?>'; self.close();">
```

I have tried this:

```
<form name="parts" id="parts" action="tableaddrow_nw.php" method="get">
<input type="button" value="Save & Close Window" class="submit" onclick="validateRow(this.form);"
```

where the `validateRow(this.form);` function is :

```
function validateRow(frm)
{
  frm.submit();
  window.opener.document.location.href='q.php?q=<?php echo $q; ?>&memberid=<?php echo $memberid; ?>';
  this.window.close();
}
```

I've also reversed the submit and reload, which I read on on posting, but it doesn't work for me.

The PHP code works just fine, since it's good in the IE10 version.  Basically, it removes previous entries, then reads the array sent in, and checks to verify that the indexes are valid, and loads the array data in again.

If I don't close the window, it works fine in both versions.  So I guess I'm hoping someone can help me still close the window on the submit, but maybe wait long enough to verify that the submit was successful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: PHP code runs on the server. It has nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: @Diodeus - I know that, just trying to be thorough in my explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this in one of my AHA! moments.

I simply used

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
    if ( $.browser.version == "10.0" ) {
        this.window.close();
    }
}
```

in order to tell IE10 just to close the window.

And in the script that is the form action (tableaddrow_nw.php) that actually spits out the data that is entered into the database, I added a "close window" button.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="button" value="Close Window" onclick="window.close()" />
</form>
```

So if it's IE8, the window doesn't close, but they get a close button.  In 1E10, the window just closes.  It's one more click for the IE8 users, but there is nothing I can do until the MAJOR supplier of industrial tools (who I won't mention by name) gets their software into something a little more modern.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the JavaScript code in the Header of your popup page (Submission Form), like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onunload = function(){
  window.opener.location.reload();
  window.close(); 
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

After Submitting the  form call the script function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function closeChildPopup()
  {

    opener.location.reload(); 
    window.close(); 
  }
</script>
```