# refresh parent window after clicking on form submit button for saving data into database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I know how to reload or refresh a parent window when we close child window using normal java script code.

But i don't know what is the best way for saving data into database after clicking submit button and same time how to close child window with reloading parent window.

In the same time the parent window will be effected by saving data from database.

And i am also trying to make a child window where the width and height will be proportional with parent window's size.

And when child window will be opened that time parent window will be totally disabled.

if someone helps me for doing it perfectly and following standard structure then it will be nice for me.

Comment: Next time please try adding spaces after full stops and using new lines.

Comment: OK.Thanks for your advice.next time i will do it perfectly.

Comment: First of all structure your question properly to get better help then show us what you have done so far.Also post your code.Also note codeigniter has nothing to do with your question as it is related to jquery,javascript or ajax.

Comment: Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321323/submit-form-reload-parent-and-close-child/36855748#36855748 might help someone